# Check if SQL input is valid SQL

Tags: php

Is there any Regular Expression to check if a string is valid SQL? It must be PHP compatible. My code.

```
if(!preg_match("regular expression", $_POST['sql_input']){
    echo "Please enter valid SQL.";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: There are many dialects of SQL, any particular one you have in mind?

Comment: What are you doing to be doing with these posted SQL queries?  `DELETE FROM users;` and `DROP DATABASE database` are valid queries ;)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/

Comment: you already asked it yesterday!

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: Maybe this guy just likes the downvotes ... -9 on the other one, -3 on this one, -18 on another one exactly the same. Sheesh.

Comment: Some are "suckers for punishment" – @webnoob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could try this library: http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/.
>   I've not used it yet so I can't guarantee it but the code looks like
>   it will be able to tell the difference between valid and invalid SQL.
>
> Another option could be to use transactions if your SQL variant allows
>   it. A transaction would allow you to execute the SQL and then cancel
>   it afterwards reversing any damage that was done. I think I would
>   prefer option 1 though.

I am quoting Godwin. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045536/is-there-a-way-for-php-to-validate-an-sql-syntax-without-executing-it)

Comment: Re: transactions, most (all?) databases won't allow you to roll back for example `DROP DATABASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. What you are trying to do is not possible.

You need an SQL Parser to check if statements are valid.

Check here: http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/vendor-specific-offline-sql-syntax-check/

Comment: Actually, it is possible (with the right sequence of `0`'s and `1`'s anything is possible nowadays ;-). I made a script using an array of keywords, and if one was found, then it would do whatever I told it to do. It could easily be modified to suit the OP's wish. Btw, I did NOT downvote this. It's not my style. ;-)

Comment: If you want to say that something is not possible, you have to demonstrate it. The other answer(s) disagree with you. (I'm the downvoter)

Comment: @STTLCU Well, to be fair I don't see a disagreeing answer that actually shows a regex or any pointer to how to construct an actual  regex for doing it either... :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You did this using regex?

Comment: I used `in_array()` @charlesisjan - No regex used.

Comment: Okay. well maybe I used the word "not possible" incorrectly. What I really meant was that regex isn't what he should be using to check if statements are valid. SQL parser is the answer!

Comment: I agree with your last comment. "there is a way, but you shouldn't do it like that but using a SQL parser" is a good answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible. But if you want to protect yourself against SQL injection attacks, there are other mechanisms you should use.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php